# ruby chef directive : include_attribute vs. include_attributes

Tags: ruby, attributes, chef-infra, cookbook

I saw this code at chef attributes file.

```
include_recipe "deployment"
include_attribute "postgresql"
include_attribute "redis"
include_attributes "uaa"
include_attributes "service_lifecycle"
```

What's different? include_attribute vs. include_attribute**S**

I cannot find any document about include_attribute**S**

Answer (score 5):

`include_attribute` attribute is used to order the way in which attributes file are loaded when converged.

If you need particular attributes loaded first, say in a wrapper cookbook [you could use this](http://docs.chef.io/attributes.html#attribute-file-ordering) to ensure precedence. This is chef 11 + only.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK there is no such thing as include_attributes. It does not do anything. Unfortunately it does not fail the chef run with some "Wrong Method" or "Cannot parse attributes" errors.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but, how about this? https://github.com/cloudfoundry/vcap/blob/master/dev_setup/cookbooks/cloud_controller/attributes/default.rb

Comment: Cannot see it here: https://github.com/opscode/chef/blob/master/lib/chef/dsl/include_attribute.rb

Comment: This is ancient but it's here: https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/master/lib/chef/dsl/include_attribute.rb